# Breaking changes between jquery 1.4.2 and 1.4.3?

Tags: jquery

Are there any known issues when upgrading from jquery 1.4.2 to 1.4.3? I'm trying to upgrade, however, in 1.4.3, NO events are firing at all. When I revert back to 1.4.2, everything works fine again. Am I missing something totally obvious?

No javascript errors are showing in the console, `$(document).ready()` is working fine and selectors are also ok, just no events firing!

Comment: Why spend time "upgrading" to such an outdated version?

Comment: It's an old site and I initially tried to upgrade to the latest version but experienced the same problems, then tried 1.6, same again, right back to 1.4.3. Don't know why you put the word upgrading in quotes though, as 1.4.2 -> 1.4.3 does constitute an upgrade, just to an older version.

Comment: This appears to be being caused by the jquery.uuid.js plugin. If I remove this plugin, events work correctly on 1.4.3. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: It looks like the UUID plugin simply has not been updated for newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: Yeah looks like it's caused by bad namespacing in the plugin code

Comment: The developer has changed the function name: https://sites.google.com/site/brazilianjoe/jquery/jquery-uuid-generator-extension

Answer (score 0):

This was being caused by the jquery.uuid.js plugin, specifically this:

```
$.uuid = function(p) {
    if (typeof (p) == 'object' && typeof (p.prefix) == 'string') {
        _uuid_default_prefix = p.prefix;
    } else {
        p = p || _uuid_default_prefix || '';
        return (p + _uuidlet() + _uuidlet() + "-" + _uuidlet() + "-" + _uuidlet() + "-" + _uuidlet() + "-" + _uuidlet() + _uuidlet() + _uuidlet());
    };
};
```

If I rename the function to $.uniqueidentifier, and rename any refs to it, events work fine in jquery 1.4.3 and any later versions. I hope no-one else has to suffer this problem!

Answer (score 0):

My website also stopped working when upgrading from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.4.3.

I use the Base.js library by Dean Edwards here: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/
Here's the snippet of my code that was causing problems:

```
asm.ui.Builder = Base.extend({
/** Element to build other elements in (hidden, accessible). */
_builderCanvas: $('<div></div>')
    .addClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible')
    .appendTo('body'),
/**
 * Creates XHTML element with supplied tag name and attributes.
 * @tparam string tag tag name
 * @tparam object attributes tag attributes
 * @treturn jQueryEl created element
 */
_buildTag: function (tag, attributes) {
    var str = '<' + tag;

    if (attributes != undefined) {
        $.each(attributes, function (name, value) {
            str += ' ' + name + '="' + value + '"';
        });
    }

    str += ($.inArray(tag, this._singleTags) != -1)
        ? '/>'
        : '></' + tag + '>';

    var newTag = $(str);
    return $(str).appendTo(this._builderCanvas);
},
...
});
```

The problem is that inside the _buildTag function, _builderCanvas was a collection of one element and so could be append to when in jQuery 1.4.2. However, in jQuery 1.4.3, _builderCanvas was still a collection but it was empty.

I worked around this by putting _builderCanvas initialization insde the _buildTag function.

**The root cause** of my problem was that in jQuery 1.4.2, if you called 'jQuery("body")' before document.body existed, it would return document.body anyway (as an optimization), whereas in jQuery 1.4.3, an additional condition (&& document.body) was added so now jQuery('body') finds nothing if called before the document is ready.

Unrelated to my problem, but one of the breaking changes from 1.4.2 to 1.4.3 is that the function .data() no longer erases all previous data, but instead adds to them.